# How to use $expand while making microsoft API call?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azureportal, azure-service-principal

I am trying to get all servicePrincipals for a tenant using this API call, I want to expand it to get ServicePrincipals role assignment, I am using the following GET request but I am not getting the required response.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/?$expand

How do I check which all fields the API can return using expand?

This is the API link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get app role assignments, simply add `$expand=appRoleAssignments` to your request URL. So your request URL will be:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$expand=appRoleAssignments
```

Comment: If OP wants to list appRoleAssignments granted for a service principal, should it be `$expand=appRoleAssignedTo`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to  [list appRoleAssignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) granted for a service principal,  can try this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$expand=appRoleAssignedTo
```

[image]